# android intents - passing data

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

**How to pass and get "myobject1" between two activities?**

First activity:

```
private ArrayList<Custom> myobject1 = new ArrayList<Custom>();
...
i.putExtra("myobject1", myobject1);
```

Second activity:

```
results =(ArrayList<Custom>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("myobject1");
```

Here is my Custom.class :

```
public class Custom implements Comparable<Custom>{


    private String big;
    private String small;

    public Custom(String n,String d)
    {
        big = n;
        small = d;

    }
    public String getFirst()
    {
        return big;
    }
    public String getSecond()
    {
        return small;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Custom o) {
        if(this.big != null)
            return this.big.toLowerCase().compareTo(o.getFirst().toLowerCase()); 
        else 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

At this moment I'm getting error:
E/AndroidRuntime(8032): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value

Comment: I think Custom needs to be Serializable

Comment: @Dikobraz To make it Serializable, just implement the `Serializable` interface to your `Custom` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass a value from an `Activity` to another the `Class` of the object you try to pass should implement the `Parcelable` interface. You can find more info here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html. In case you need anything more specific, please shoot it!